# Running MATLAB script in a bash loop

Tags: bash, matlab

I need to run a MATLAB script inside a bash loop. I'm aware of the syntax which goes as follows:

```
for i in "${img[@]}"
do
    echo $i
    matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "myfunction('$i','cropped_$i');quit;"
done
```

It works as it should, however, I find it extremely annoying that it has to quit and open MATLAB every iteration, greatly increasing computation time. Is there any way to run it more natively without having to close/open every iteration?

Comment: why not pass your for loop on to matlab?

Comment: Why not load your images directly in MATLAB?

Comment: You can't "daemonize" matlab. However matlab is a great scripting language for what you're trying to do, just write the whole thing in a matlab script and call that from bash with the `-r` flag.

Comment: "*I need to run a MATLAB script inside a bash loop*" - **Why**?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MATLAB. If I can't do it from bash, I'll try putting everything together in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the loop in Matlab is clearly the superior answer, although I don't know Matlab well enough to present that as an answer. Another option is to construct the Matlab code dynamically.

```
for i in "${img[@]}"; do
    code+="myfunction('$i', 'cropped_$i');"
done
code+="quit;"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "$code"
```